# Qual è il significato di "dare otto ai venti" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> Per tutta risposta l’avanguardista ti rivolse una sfida. «Se **mi dài otto ai venti**» ti disse, «giochiamo dieci lire.» Per schermirti gli rifiutasti il vantaggio, ma la platea ti fu addosso ad una voce.

Si tratta di una scena in cui stanno giocando a ping-pong.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "mi dài otto ai venti" in questo brano. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'avanguardista propone all'avversario che se gli avesse dato un vantaggio di 8 punti sui 20, punteggio che decreta il vincitore della partita, era disposto a scommettere 10 lire.

L'avversario viene considerato dall'avanguardista più forte e quindi gli fa un velato complimento, visto che è convinto di non riuscire a batterlo partendo dallo 0 a 0.

Comment: Quindi, infatti l'avanguardista voleva partire con 8 punti?

Comment: @Charo Proprio così. Infatti l’avversario si schermisce, quasi fosse in imbarazzo e il pubblico rumoreggia perché lo considera più forte e la partita non avrebbe storia

Comment: Cosa significa "non avrebbe storia"?

Comment: È un modo di dire che si usa quando, ad esempio, il divario tra due avversari è talmente ampio che il risultato è prevedibile in partenza. L’incontro diventa senza storia cioè dal risultato scontato.